# Installed applications in descending order of use?

Tags: windows, file-management

To move from an old XP host to a new Windows 7 host, I need to go through the list of applications that I use. Ideally, I'd like to find a (GUI) tool that list all installed applications in descending order of use, so that I can check what is worth moving to the new host.

The archives showed a number of applications, but the one I know, SIW, doesn't provide this information. Does someone know if there's a reliable application that does this?

- WMIC www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/wmic.mspx?mfr=true
- PsInfo http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897550.aspx
- http://ccleaner.com/
- SIW - System Information for Windows http://www.gtopala.com/
- Belarc Advisor http://www.belarc.com
- www.spiceworks.com/free-pc-network-inventory-software/

Thank you.

Comment: I would have said that the Add/Remove programs dialog in Control Panel supplies this information, but I don't have an XP machine to hand to check.

Comment: The "Last Used On" date in the XP Add/Remove Programs app is notoriously unreliable.  For example, it claims I last ran Google Chrome on 10/20/2009 yet it's my daily browser.

Comment: @gordoco, I see what you mean: most of my factory programs only have an install date and show blank dates --even under Vista. I have a hunch that they just touch "last date" based on whether the program ever writes to the registry or modifies its appointed C:\Program Files\ subfolder. Because that folder is write-protected nowadays Chrome gets around that that by changing only outside places even if Exe files are updated. I haven't seen any tool to help you. Go into program files with some pie-chart tool (http://www.megaleecher.net/taxonomy/term/3393) and delete fuzzily based on your memory

Comment: I guess I could write a script that uses NTFS to check the last time each binary was last executed and build a list.